# Which innovations (like MVC, xunit, Hotspot) did Smalltalk bring?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, smalltalk

I find more and more aspects where Smalltalk was the innovator, i.e. created the technique or at least the overall concept for the first time. I can think of the following:

- [xunit approach](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Xunit.html)
- [IDE concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeak)
- [VM optimizations](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/docs/whitepaper/Java_HotSpot_WP_Final_4_30_01.html)
- [fluent interfaces](http://www.bofh.org.uk/2005/12/21/fluent-interfaces)
- several [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern) (e.g. [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))
- the [class-free prototype paradigm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/115418/29043).

**Are all of these correct? Which further innovations did Smalltalk bring?**

I'm sure there are more (e.g. in the field of language design?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The mouse
- Unit Testing
- Refactoring
- Scavenging GC
- image concept (snapshot)

Comment: Of course, I forgot refactoring (+1). I think providing links would make your answer even better. For instance, I do not know what you mean by your last item.

Comment: Not the mouse. That's Doug Engelbart. I suspect that scavenging GCs and images came from the Lisp community.

Comment: Source:http://goo.gl/PX8ao                                             
_The first person to use refactoring phrase in print was Ralph Johnson, but it’s believed that he most likely learned about it from Smalltalk programmers at Tektronix.  He and Bill Opdyke wrote a paper about refactoring in 1990 with emphasis on the importance of refactoring in the design of frameworks.  Then Bill Opdyke wrote a PhD thesis on refactoring in 1992.  Furthermore, John Brant and Don Roberts built the Refactoring Browser for Smalltalk, and Don wrote a PhD thesis on it in 1999._

Answer (score 3):

It is the first language that was a clear improvement on a large majority of its successors (with the possible exceptions of *self* and *newspeak*). If you want to see the future of java and c#, look no further than smalltalk.

Comment: Smalltalk is the first language that was a clear improvement on a large majority of Smalltalk's successors?

Comment: Yes. Or if seen from another perspective: the people trying to bolt on OOP to other languages didn't take a good enough look at what was important in smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Dan Ingalls is usually given credit for inventing [BitBLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) as part of Smalltalk 72.

I would also add "IDE" to the list, but I have no citation to back that up.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one **BIG** thing: object-oriented programming

Comment: Doh. We didn't see the OO-wood for all the innovation-trees ( +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that smalltalk implemented the first window based GUI. Hard to beat that ;)

Comment: Yup, I think I read that somewhere, too. Do you happen to have a reference?

Comment: Well I might be a bit wrong on this , but it was one of the firsts most certainly. More info can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Alto

Comment: Thanks for the link. So the Xerox Alto, which had the first mouse-driven GUI, also contained the first Smalltalk environment. But the GUI was not implemented in Smalltalk itself.

Answer (score 0):

Domain-Driven Design: Trygve Renskaug's papers on the MVC pattern discuss heavily the importance of representing the domain of the system in the object model and separating it from the conceptual view.